# Cordova Push Notification ios

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins

I am trying to set up a push notification from the cordova phonegap push plugin, which processes through node and the command line interface. However the conosole says 
"didRecieveNotification" and "Notification Received" but nothing comes out through the phone.

My code for the apn is as follows:

```
var apn = require('apn');

var options = { };

var token = 'Phone ID';

var apnConnection = new apn.Connection(options);

var myDevice = new apn.Device(token);

var message = new apn.Notification();

message.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
message.badge = 3;
message.sound = "ping.aiff";
message.alert = "\uD83D\uDCE7 \u2709 You have a new message";
message.payload = {'messageFrom': 'Caroline'};`

apnConnection.pushNotification(message, myDevice);
```

And my index.js which tries to call the notification:

```
  receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
            pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler,{"senderID":"ID","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});
         }
         else {
            pushNotification.register(this.tokenHandler,this.errorHandler,   {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"app.onNotificationAPN"});
        }
},
successHandler: function(result) {
    alert('Callback Success! Result = '+result)
},
errorHandler:function(error) {
    alert(error);
},
successHandler: function(result) {
    alert('Callback Success! Result = '+result)
},
errorHandler:function(error) {
    alert(error);
},
 onNotificationAPN: function(event) {
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    console.log("Received a notification! " + event.alert);
    console.log("event sound " + event.sound);
    console.log("event badge " + event.badge);
    console.log("event " + event);
    if (event.alert) {
        navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
    }
    if (event.badge) {
        console.log("Set badge on  " + pushNotification);
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(this.successHandler, event.badge);
    }
    if (event.sound) {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
    }
},

onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                    alert('registration id = '+e.regid);
                }
            break;

            case 'message':
              // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
              alert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt);
            break;

            case 'error':
              alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
            break;

            default:
              alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
              break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The notification only appears if the application is on background. Try doing it with the device in the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Try copying all the files from platforms/ios/platform_www/ to platforms/ios/www and build the app. I had the same problem and it worked for me.